# Can it be possible that there is no linear relationship when correlation coefficient is positive?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I have least square regression line

$y=0.0008x + 1.7345$ with correlation coefficient ($\rho$) $= 0.3842$

it seems like that there is weak positive linear relationship

However,

When I use inference for regression to show that there is sufficient evidence to conclude that there is positive linear relationship,

$H_0: β=0$ 
$H_a: β>0 $

I figured out that estimated standard error or deviation of slope is $0.328928$

With 40 observations, my df$=38$

T value is 0.0008/0.328928 which has really small, which shows that P-value is really large that If I test it at $\alpha=10\%$, we can not reject null hypothesis.

So, there is no evidence to conclude that there is positive linear relationship.

What I do not understand is that

based on regression line, we see that there is somewhat positive relationship since $\rho= 0.3842$.

In fact, at $\alpha=10\%$, there is no evidence to reject null hypothesis.

What can I conclude from these two facts?

Comment: Could you show your output?  I suspect you have misread or miscopied some result, because when r = .384 and n = 40, p = .01.  Maybe your regression coefficient was affected by the inclusion of one or more other predictors.